# Access a Remote SQL Server which on Colab

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, google-colaboratory

I am quite new to working on remote servers so apologize if this is a silly question, but I couldn't find any instructions anywhere.

I have access to a remote DataBase from University but I need to make a connection through Pulse Secure to access it. (And then I use mySQL workbench to do so). Now I need to get the data to work on Deep Learning, in Colab or anywhere else on the cloud. But I have no idea how to do this. I tried using mySQLdb but it didn't work to get a connection.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example how to install MySQL in Colab and query it. You can change the connection to your university remote database.

```py
# install, set connection
!apt-get install mysql-server > /dev/null
!service mysql start
!mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'"
!pip -q install PyMySQL
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.feedback=False 
%config SqlMagic.autopandas=True
%sql mysql+pymysql://root:root@/
# query using %sql or %%sql
df = %sql SELECT Host, User, authentication_string FROM mysql.user
df
```